# SharePoint Online Is Copying Metadata From Other Files

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to disable SharePoint from applying metadata from a copied file?

[image: sharepoint example]

In the attached image you can see that copy_00.xlsx is set to version 1.0 but TextField and DateField are populated from the values of original_00.xlsx.

The fields do not have default values.
This is happening in the classic and modern SPO experience.

Create an XLSX file
Upload to a library and apply metadata values
Download and rename the file
Upload the file to the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is OOTB property promotion / demotion at work. You can try to disable it using PowerShell.
One possible workaround is to open the file after downloading, remove the metadata, save the file and then upload the modified file.
Paul | SLIM Applications

Comment: thank you!  I have NO idea why anyone would want this enabled OOTB and it's causing a massive issue for me.  Again, thank you!

Comment: Agree, It causes lots of problems when folks start copying/moving documents. I have seen this at several customers. One ends up with a mix of documents with incorrect security classification, project numbers etc..Offering functionality to enable/disable the property promotion or demotion per site or library would be ideal. An alternative it would be useful if the move/copy operation or download can offer an extra option to strip metadata present in the files.

Comment: I've opened a ticket with Microsoft to see if they can flip the switch from their side. The $web.ParserEnabled property is not available to people using SPO. Fun times

Comment: Opening a ticket with Microsoft was a waste of time.  Really starting to miss on-prem SP, a lot!

Comment: did you spend any time looking into creating a remote event receiver to help with this issue?

Comment: this is news to me, but you can set ParserDisabled at the library level in SPO.  More info:  https://www.sharepointed.com/2021/03/sharepoint-online-and-copied-metadata/

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to disable Document Property Promotion using PowerShell in SharePoint Online since the **ParserEnabled** property is not settable in Microsoft 365 tenants.

You can remove the file properties in Office client via `Excel > File > Info > Show All Properties` and then find the custom properties in the **Properties** list.

[image]

Reference:
[Support the Web.ParserEnabled property in CSOM.](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/15147189-support-the-web-parserenabled-property-in-csom)

Answer (score 0):

Setting ParserDisable to $true is available at the library level in SharePoint Online.

Basic PowerShell:

```
$List.ParserDisabled = $true
$List.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Longer example here:
https://www.sharepointed.com/2021/03/sharepoint-online-and-copied-metadata/

@Paul